# Animate collapse and expand of table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, tableview

I've a `UITableView` with expandable cells, when you click on a cell - it expands and other opened cell collapses at the same time with animation.

Here is my code:

**UITableViewDelegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cellToCollapse = getExpandedCell()
  if let cellToExpand = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell {

    // Make animation for collapse and expand happen together
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
      cellToExpand.expand()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      cellToCollapse?.collapse()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
      // This reloads cells' height
      tableView?.beginUpdates()
      tableView?.endUpdates()
    }
  }
}
```

**MyTableViewCell**

```
func expand() {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
    animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
    if let frame = self?.collapsibleView.frame {
      self?.collapsibleView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        }
      },
    completion: { _ in
      self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    })
}

func collapse() {
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2,
    animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
    if let frame = self?.collapsibleView.frame {
      self?.collapsibleView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: frame.width, height: 0)
      }
    },
    completion: { _ in
      self.collapsibleView.removeFromSuperview()
      self.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    })
}
```

This code works great.

My question is - is it correct to be using `asyncAfter` in this case?
I  would prefer using a completion block here, however, I don't want to pass `tableView` to `MyTableViewCell`.

Comment: Could use a different (simpler?) approach. Keep a `var toCollapse: IndexPath?`, In `heightForRowAt` delegate function `return toCollapse == indexPath ? 0 : kHeightCell`. In `didSelectRowAt` function just do this `toCollapse = indexPath; tableView.beginUpdates(); tableView.endUpdates()`. UITableView will handle the animation.